# set this macro as an environment variable in the build environment?

Tags: visual-studio, build, msbuild, macros, environment-variables

There is an option in Visual Studio when setting macros in project property sheets that says

`set this macro as an environment variable in the build environment`

for example in below window:

[image]

What is the purpose of this checkbox?
I have a lot of macros defined in VS, and having this checkbox checked or unchecked does not show any apparent purpose so far.

Comment: This is relevant only to C and C++ projects.  Languages that in general use traditional command line build tools, the kind that often use environment variables.  Like INCLUDE for the compiler and LIB for the linker.  Anything is possible.  You'll know when you need this checkbox.

Comment: thanks man for suggestion! see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have testing suggestion posted by Hans Passant in comment below my question and come up with good idea!

Run MSYS2 shell from within Visual Studio, by using build event in property sheet.

property sheet that **defines** a macro with `set this macro as an environment variable in the build environment`

When I build project it opens MSYS2 shell and import all the macros into the shell.

Now I just call bash shell script attached to project and have Visual Studio use GNU build system!! YES!

autotools in Visual Studio.
Thanks Hans!